# Moving partitions with YaST Expert Partitioner: "already created on disk and cannot be moved"

Tags: linux, virtualbox, partitioning, opensuse, yast

I am currently trying to use the YaST partitioner tool (on openSUSE 13.2 under VirtualBox) to move the Linux swap partition on a VirtualBox virtual disk image. Upon trying to move any given partition on the virtual disk, I get the error "The partition /dev/sdb< x > is already created on disk and cannot be moved." In addition, I cannot seem to resize any partition beyond its already existing size despite the fact that I have 40.82 GB of unpartitioned space on the virtual disk.

I have read that this supposedly can be caused by having the disk mounted, but, as far as I can tell, the disk is not mounted (none of the partitions under `sdb` have a Mount Point, and `mount` does not show any of the partitions on this virtual disk).

Have I made a mistake, and, if not, is there a way to resolve this issue?

**Edit:** The following is a screenshot of where I am in the YaST partitioner tool:

[image]

Comment: Is the virtual disk fully mapped out, or is it set to grow the disk as more space is needed?

Comment: @brianlmerritt The virtual disk is a dynamically allocated virtual hard disk (the latter). I can try cloning the hard disk to a fixed sized virtual disk and using that to see if it will help.

Comment: Not guaranteed, but just a thought that a virtual virtual partition may be an issue

Comment: @brianlmerritt Unfortunately, it seems that using a fixed-size clone of the disk makes no difference; I get the same errors/problems.

Comment: Maybe edit your question and screen snapshot your Yast partitions ? Also please note: https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/467038-Moving-a-logical-partition

Comment: @brianlmerritt Thanks. I added the screenshot. I had already read that thread, and I believe the solution was that the user should try a GParted LiveCD because the partition was mounted. As stated in the post, I don't think that the partition is mounted. It also seems that the GParted LiveCD does not work with VirtualBox. Also, I would like to try to figure out why this isn't working with YaST Expert Partitioner, if, indeed, as one poster stated "YaST can do it as well as any other tool."

Answer (score 0):

YaST doesn't allow partitions already on disk to be moved—the feature is only there for moving partitions you've added prior to writing them to disk. This can be a problem if it's a data partition as deleting and recreating it would result in data loss, but since this is a swap partition, no data would be lost on doing so.

What you'll need to do is delete the extended partition `sdb2`, which will also delete `sdb5`. From there, you can recreate the swap partition at the end of the disk, which will allow you to expand the data partition `sdb1` as needed. I'd recommend that you don't create an extended partition unless you expect to need more than four partitions on the disk. (If you do need more than four partitions, you should probably be using GPT instead.)

Comment: The suggested procedure works, but I do not understand the explanation. `fdisk -l` shows that the `sdb2` partition starts at 100665342 and ends at 104855551. Wouldn't the end be much greater if the extended partition includes all of the space that YaST lists as "Unpartitioned"?

Comment: Also, why is it that the YaST cannot move partitions already existing on the disk? I remember a few tutorials (such as  [this one](http://trivialproof.blogspot.com/2011/01/resizing-virtualbox-virtual-hard-disk.html) suggested that the swap partition be moved in order to enable resizing of the main partition, but all of these tutorials involved using GParted. Is the ability to move partitions like this a feature that GParted has, but YaST Expert Partitioner lacks?

Comment: Most likely—I'm not familiar with GParted, but from what I know, it can move existing partitions, which YaST can't. I'm rather confused about the `fdisk -l` output, though. It might be a quirk with the way it handles extended partitions...

Comment: No the extended partition (sdb2) is not created till the end of the disk. You can see that as well in YaST partitioner that it ends at the same point as the swap partition (sdb5) inside it. Also, look at their sizes, both are `2.00 GiB`.

Comment: Can't revise at this time, but will look into it tomorrow. Logical partitions still need to be contiguous to avoid wasting space, from what I'm reading.